# Scaffold key - what the purpose is and where it is used

Tags: flutter, dart

What is scaffoldKey what the purpose is and where it is used?

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
        return  Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: AppBar(
               ....................
```

Answer (score 0):

A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the key. ... currentState property to obtain the ScaffoldState rather than using the Scaffold. of() function.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

`Scaffold` is just a widget, and the `key` property of any widget preserves state when that widget is moved in a tree.  Per [the documentation for the key property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html):

> Controls how one widget replaces another widget in the tree.
>
> If the runtimeType and key properties of the two widgets are
> operator==, respectively, then the new widget replaces the old widget
> by updating the underlying element (i.e., by calling Element.update
> with the new widget). Otherwise, the old element is removed from the
> tree, the new widget is inflated into an element, and the new element
> is inserted into the tree.
>
> In addition, using a GlobalKey as the widget's key allows the element
> to be moved around the tree (changing parent) without losing state.
> When a new widget is found (its key and type do not match a previous
> widget in the same location), but there was a widget with that same
> global key elsewhere in the tree in the previous frame, then that
> widget's element is moved to the new location.
>
> Generally, a widget that is the only child of another widget does not
> need an explicit key.

[Here is a helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) from the Flutter team which goes into greater depth on when and where to use keys and the various types of keys you might use, depending on the situation.  The section of the video at [2:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&t=140s) is particularly informative.